# Does it make sense to reuse the same array instead of declaring a new one?

Tags: java, rx-java

Does it make sense to reuse the same array instead of declaring in `.collectInto`?

```
return loadSortedSparseNumbersObservable()
    .collectInto(
            new numbers[1000],
            (array, number) -> {
                int index = computeTrueIndex(...);
                array[index] = number;
            }
    )
    .map(array -> );
```

We can probably replace the code above with something like:

```
long[] array = new long[700];
return loadSortedSparseNumbersObservable()
        .doOnNext(
                Arrays.fill(array, 0L),
                (array, number) -> {
                    int index = computeTrueIndex(...);
                    array[index] = number;
                }
        )
        .toCompletable()
        .andThen(Single.just(array))
        .map(array -> );
```

I don't really like mutating object though.

Comment: If you reuse the array, anybody that has an older version will find that it changes without warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example has more operators thus potentially more overhead and of course is uglier to read and understand.

The big gotcha in both your examples is that the returned `Observable` is not reusable safely. Concurrent calls to that same `Observable` would interact on the array. The safe way to do that is to create a new array for every subscription. Use `collect` instead of `collectInto`:

```
return loadSortedSparseNumbersObservable()
    .collect(
            () -> new numbers[1000],
            (array, number) -> {
                int index = computeTrueIndex(...);
                array[index] = number;
            }
    )
    .map(array -> );
```

Comment: Why should I use collect instead of collectInto though?

Comment: Note that the array creation is a lambda with collect so that every subscriber gets its own array.

Answer (score 0):

The concern in modifying the array in-place is thread-safety. Arrays in Java are pass-by-reference so any reuse/modification of an array could cause concurrency problems in other parts of a program.

The question, though, doesn't give insight as to the structure or function of the code that is using this particular array, so there may be an application-specific reason to modify in-place. Likewise, there may be a very compelling reason not to.